# Kohana constructor purpose

Tags: php, kohana

As far as Kohana is concerned, can you give me a short sentence or two as to WHEN and WHY I need to use a `constructor` within my controller? After a LOT of reading, I can't seem to wrap my tiny little brain around the `constructor` concept. Looking for "layman's terms" here. =)

**Edit:** Question pertains to Kohana v2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**The Documentation**](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/controllers#construct):

> If you declare a constructor in your controller, for example *to load some resources for the entire controller*, you have to call the parent constructor.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(); // This must be included

    $this->db = Database::instance();
    $this->session = Session::instance();
}
```

You can see in this example, the documentation demonstrates calling the parent constructor, and then setting up some properties for the class itself that will reference the database connection, and the session.

Comment: Do you actually need $this? I'm just getting into this framework thing and it sometimes gets me how many things you got to throw in front of a function.

Comment: @Kyle This is a rather old question. If you're just getting into Kohana, you're probably using Kohana 3.1. That being said, I'd check out the relevant documentation for the present version. Don't be dismayed, Kohana was and still is a beautiful framework that you'll love working with :)

Answer (score 0):

You see each of your controllers extends the parent controller. For the parent controller to run or import it's functionality into your controller, you need to a constructor in your controller. The parent adds/sets set's functionality behavior of your controllers.

Hope that makes sense, thanks :)